# FreeRADIUS3 - ERROR: Failed parsing output from exec, expecting operator

Tags: freeradius

FreeRADIUS 3 for OTP authentication, authentication succeeds, however FreeRADIUS fails to parse the response.

Sending the test command and monitoring the debug output (`radiusd -X`), there is an error as shown below, where the output is not parsed even though the response from the external program appears to be satisfactory:

```sh
# below, totp.py generates a TOTP for johnboy, to aid testing
# using pyotp package to make testing easier...

radtest -t mschap johnboy $(./totp.py) localhost 0 testing123
```

```
.
.
.
(4) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(4)     [eap] = noop
(4)     [expiration] = noop
(4)     [logintime] = noop
(4) multiotp: Executing: /usr/local/bin/multiotp.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' -request-nt-key -src=%{Packet-Src-IP-Address} -chap-challenge=%{CHAP-Challenge} -chap-password=%{CHAP-Password} -ms-chap-challenge=%{MS-CHAP-Challenge} -ms-chap-response=%{MS-CHAP-Response} -ms-chap2-response=%{MS-CHAP2-Response}:
(4) multiotp: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(4) multiotp:    --> johnboy
(4) multiotp: EXPAND %{User-Password}
(4) multiotp:    --> 
(4) multiotp: EXPAND -src=%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}
(4) multiotp:    --> -src=127.0.0.1
(4) multiotp: EXPAND -chap-challenge=%{CHAP-Challenge}
(4) multiotp:    --> -chap-challenge=
(4) multiotp: EXPAND -chap-password=%{CHAP-Password}
(4) multiotp:    --> -chap-password=
(4) multiotp: EXPAND -ms-chap-challenge=%{MS-CHAP-Challenge}
(4) multiotp:    --> -ms-chap-challenge=0xf54c102e95a800d8
(4) multiotp: EXPAND -ms-chap-response=%{MS-CHAP-Response}
(4) multiotp:    --> -ms-chap-response=0x0001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e3004419ce4b084c0b073836fd40f3828fcc7c4223b0dcc5
(4) multiotp: EXPAND -ms-chap2-response=%{MS-CHAP2-Response}
(4) multiotp:    --> -ms-chap2-response=
(4) multiotp: ERROR: Failed parsing output from: /usr/local/bin/multiotp.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' -request-nt-key -src=%{Packet-Src-IP-Address} -chap-challenge=%{CHAP-Challenge} -chap-password=%{CHAP-Password} -ms-chap-challenge=%{MS-CHAP-Challenge} -ms-chap-response=%{MS-CHAP-Response} -ms-chap2-response=%{MS-CHAP2-Response}: Expecting opera
tor
(4) multiotp: ERROR: Program returned code (0) and output 'Filter-Id += "<user_group>",NT_KEY: A7C014D1209A4078F1003810BDB08BE6  '
(4)     [multiotp] = fail
(4)   } # authorize = fail
(4) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(4) # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(4)   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you paste what's inside multitop?

Answer (score 1):

From the [FreeRADIUS mailing list](http://freeradius.1045715.n5.nabble.com/module-fails-parsing-output-expecting-operator-td5756859.html), the response from MultiOTP `'Filter-Id += "<user_group>",NT_KEY: A7C014D1209A4078F1003810BDB08BE6  '` is not valid for FreeRADIUS 3, but may well have worked with FreeRADIUS 2.

I worked around this problem by using a wrapper script to parse the output from [MultiOTP[(https://github.com/multiOTP/multiotp), returning only the part 'Filter-Id += "Erica-Users' for the 'authenticate' section's 'exec' step, and returning only the 'NT_KEY: A7C014D1209A4078F1003810BDB08BE6' part for the 'authorize' step's 'mschap' step within the FreeRADIUS auth process.

> It is worth noting the documentation for FreeRADIUS 3 with MultiOTP in the [MultiOTP README.md](https://github.com/multiOTP/multiotp/blob/master/README.md), and repeated on the [FreeRADIUS Wiki](https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/multiOTP-HOWTO), are not, at time of writing and it does not suggest file names which are actually used with FreeRADIUS 3.
>
> The configuration steps for MultiOTP itself are accurate.
>
> [FreeRADIUS 3](https://freeradius.org/) has excellent documentation on-line [here](https://networkradius.com/doc/current/index.html), and a polite and helpful [mailing list](https://freeradius.org/support/).

For anyone grappling the same problem, here are some code snippets for a FreeRADIUS 3 configuration. I have not shown the virtual server configuration file, which may be more specific to an particular environment.

/usr/local/bin/multiotp_wrapper_mschap.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Extract Filter-Id

user_name=$1
user_password=$2
packet_src_ip_address=$3
ms_chap_challange=$4
ms_chap_response=$5

/usr/local/bin/multiotp.php ${user_name} ${user_password} -request-nt-key -src=${packet_src_ip_address} -ms-chap-challenge=${ms_chap_challange} -ms-chap-response=${ms_chap_response} | sed -e 's/.*,//'
```

/usr/local/bin/multiotp_wrapper_exec.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Extract NT_KEY

user_name=$1
user_password=$2
packet_src_ip_address=$3
ms_chap_challange=$4
ms_chap_response=$5

/usr/local/bin/multiotp.php ${user_name} ${user_password} -request-nt-key -src=${packet_src_ip_address} -ms-chap-challenge=${ms_chap_challange} -ms-chap-response=${ms_chap_response} | sed -e 's/,NT_KEY.*$//'
```

/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/multiotp:

```
exec multiotp {  
  wait = yes
  input_pairs = request
  output_pairs = reply
  program = "/usr/local/bin/multiotp_wrapper_exec.sh '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' %{Packet-Src-IP-Address} %{MS-CHAP-Challenge} %{MS-CHAP-Response}"
  shell_escape = yes
}
```

/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/multiotpmschap:

```
mschap multiotpmschap {
  # ntlm_auth = "/usr/local/bin/multiotp.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' -request-nt-key -src=%{Packet-Src-IP-Address} -chap-challenge=%{CHAP-Challenge} -chap-password=%{CHAP-Password} -ms-chap-challenge=%{MS-CHAP-Challenge} -ms-chap-response=%{MS-CHAP-Response} -ms-chap2-response=%{MS-CHAP2-Response}"
  ntlm_auth = "/usr/local/bin/multiotp_wrapper_mschap.sh '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' %{Packet-Src-IP-Address} %{MS-CHAP-Challenge} %{MS-CHAP-Response}"
  pool {
    start = ${thread[pool].start_servers}
    min = ${thread[pool].min_spare_servers}
    max = ${thread[pool].max_servers}
    spare = ${thread[pool].max_spare_servers}
    uses = 0
    retry_delay = 30
    lifetime = 86400
    cleanup_interval = 300
    idle_timeout = 600
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others got the "ERROR: Failed parsing output", please check the "display log" option in multiotp.ini, if it is enabled, it may also cause the issue.

refer:
https://github.com/multiOTP/multiotp/issues/125